How to redirect an url with a specific folder to another, whatever the page?
I tried for hours to redirect in an htaccess every pages of a folder to new url, matching the folder but it seems I definitely do not understand nothing to regex and redirect !
I want to redirect any pages into the folder /folder/ to a totally different url
Something like
RedirectMatch 301 ^/folder$ https://www.mynewdomain.com/id/2176

in order to redirect https://www.myolddomain.com/folder/123.html to https://www.mynewdomain.com/id/2176
I do not want to keep anything of previous url, just redirect any page of this folder to a specific url.
Someone can help ?
Thanx
I tried
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule /folder/ https://www.mynewdomain.com/id/2176

but it do not work, i am not redirected when i reach an url containing /folder/. Tried
RewriteRule ^/folder(/)?$ https://www.mynewdomain.com/id/2176 [R=301,L]


https://regex101.com/r/S0aTqy/1 Your regex is missing a wildcard pattern  for everything that comes after /path/to/folder

Sorry, it do not works, i added RewriteRule /folder/(.) https://www.mynewdomain.com/id/2176, folder/(.), ^folder(.), ^/folder(.), /folder/?(.*)... but nothing work, wathever i tried, nothing works

You don't need a "wildcard pattern" (and it certainly doesn't need to be capturing). You just don't need the end-of-string anchor ($) on the end of the pattern. @Marc


RedirectMatch 301 ^/folder$ https://www.mynewdomain.com/id/2176


The end-of-string anchor ($) marks the end of the URL-path that is matched. So, this matches /folder and nothing else. You need to remove the end-of-string anchor. ie. ^/folder. So this matches any URL-path that starts with /folder. However, this potentially matches too much, as it would also match any file in the root that simply starts with the text folder (this may or may not be an issue in your case). To avoid this and match only requests for the folder and files within that folder (and subfolders) then use the regex ^/folder($|/) instead.
Note that RedirectMatch is a mod_alias directive.

RewriteRule /folder/ https://www.mynewdomain.com/id/2176


Whereas RewriteRule is a mod_rewrite directive. In .htaccess the URL-path matched by the RewriteRule pattern does not start with a slash. So, you need to match against the URL-path folder/ instead (not /folder/).
Bringing the above points together, if you are using mod_rewrite then you would need the following:
RewriteRule ^folder($|/) https://www.mynewdomain.com/id/2176 [R=301,L]

Note also the addition of the flags argument. This is a permanent 301 redirect. And consequently will be chached by browsers.
You should always test with 302 (temporary) redirects to avoid caching issues. And clear your browser cache before testing.
Note also, the order of these directives in your .htaccess file can also be significant. Generally, redirects like this would need to be near the top of the file.
